# Modifying php.ini without editing the actual file

Tags: php, webserver

is that even possible?.. OsCommerce need these settings,

register_globals       -->       on
magic_quotes_gpc       -->       off

but unfortunately I am not allowed to edit the php.ini file because of shared hosting.. 
is any otherway to do it? I got only FTP access.

**edit:**

**PHP Version** 5.2.17

**Server API**  CGI/FastCGI

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this at runtime using `ini_set` more about it here: http://php.net/ini_set

Comment: WHat's the PHP version you're running?

Comment: Maybe you hosting company alowed to make changes with `.htaccess`. I have kloxo cpanel, and I can make changes with `.htaccess` like `<Ifmodule mod_php5.c>
 
 php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on
 php_flag magic_quotes_runtime on
</Ifmodule>` and so...

Comment: @user1909426 that is not true for PHP5

Comment: Do a `phpinfo()` and post the values for `Server API`, `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` and `Additional .ini files parsed`. This might help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "ini_set" at the top of your PHP script.

Documentation for ini_set is here: http://www.php.net/ini_set

I am not sure how OsCommerce works, but hopefully there is a main index.php file, and you would only have to modify that one.

Worst case scenario is that there is a mass of PHP files everywhere that would need to be modified.

Comment: It should work if the PHP version is <= 4.2.3.  Care to expand on how it wouldn't work?

Comment: The two directives OP mentioned cannot be changed via `ini_set`. Also, PHP 4.2.3 is ancient.

Answer (score 0):

Not all ini variables are changeable through ini_set. But some variables canbe changed in a custom php.ini.

In this case, you can't change `magic_quotes_gpc` and `register_globals` through `ini_set()` but you are allowed to change in `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, that is, if your server allows you to create a custom php.ini, then you can change it there.